# Images not displaying on iPhone ios7 Safari

Tags: ios, css, iphone, svg, safari

I built a simple landing page for a client (http://www.smithandwollensky.london/), however images aren't displaying on my  iPhone - using ios7 Safari. I've been through everything I can thing of to solve the issue (made sure I'm using correct MIME types, simplifying the HTML), but I'm having no luck.

Things I think it could be related to:

- Site is hosted static site on Amazon S3
- Page uses .svg images with .png fallbacks
- ios7 not ios8 version of Safari

Has anyone else had similar issues with this sort of website?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was down to Amazon S3 serving a .svg without the correct MIME type - so Safari wasn't processing it correctly, causing it to break the .jpg that was located directly after it too.

Fixed the issue by moving the images to an Apache server.